Can I land in ILS CAT I when no RVR info is available and VIS is 700m? According to easa
Category I (CAT I): a DH not lower than 60 m (200 ft) and with either a visibility not less than 800 m or a RVR not less than 550 m

I was wondering if it is legal to convert VIS to RVR and land when calculated RVR is above 550m

If the visibility was 800 meters or above when you entered the final approach segment or 1,000 feet and then dropped to 700 meters, you could still land if you have the required visual reference when you reach the DH of 200 feet.
If the visibility is 700 meters before the final approach segment or 1,000 feet, the approach ban would apply.
See "approach ban" and "required visual reference" EASA (CAT.OP.MPA.305)
For ease of reference

(a) The commander or the pilot to whom conduct of the flight has been
delegated may commence an instrument approach regardless of the
reported RVR/VIS.
(b) If the reported RVR/VIS is less than the applicable minimum the
approach shall not be continued:
(1)  below 1000 ft above the aerodrome; or
(2)  into the final approach segment in the case where the DA/H or
MDA/H is more than 1000 ft above the aerodrome.
(c) Where the RVR is not available, RVR values may be derived by
converting the reported visibility.
(d) If, after passing 1000 ft above the aerodrome, the reported
RVR/VIS falls below the applicable minimum, the approach may be
continued to DA/H or MDA/H.
(e) The approach may be continued below DA/H or MDA/H and the landing
may be completed provided that the visual reference adequate for the
type of approach operation and for the intended runway is established
at the DA/H or MDA/H and is maintained.
(f) The touchdown zone RVR shall always be controlling. If reported
and relevant, the midpoint and stopend RVR shall also be controlling.
The minimum RVR value for the midpoint shall be 125 m or the RVR
required for the touchdown zone if less, and 75 m for the stopend. For
aircraft equipped with a rollout guidance or control system, the
minimum RVR value for the midpoint shall be 75 m.

You may convert the visibilty to RVR according to the table, see (c) above.

I was wondering if it is legal to convert VIS to RVR and land when
calculated RVR is above 550m

